# Выбор API в android-support-v7-appcompat

Tags: android-appcompat

Установил android-support-v7-appcompat для работы с тулбаром. Подключил его к моему проекту (в манифесте проекта Api 15-22). Если в Properties\Android проекта android-support-v7-appcompat ставлю Api 22 - то он ругается на values-v23\styles_base.xml, а мой проект при компиляции выдает ошибки:

> workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>
> workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Если обоим проектам поставить Api 23 - часть кода в моем проекте краснеет, но мне поддержка Api 23 не нужна.

Как побороть?

Comment: Либо ставить api 23 либо использовать appcompat 22 версии.

Comment: А как поставить appcompat 22 версии? Скачать отдельно и заменить папку v7 с 23 версией на 22?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

Comment: Не могу нигде найти 22 версию. Если все-таки оставить 23 (так наверно правильней будет), с кодом постараюсь разобраться, а можно будет потом как-то запретить установку на устройства с Api 23?

Comment: Почему eclipse все равно ругается на setLatestEventInfo?    final int sdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);    if (sdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {    /*код*/    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,    context.getResources().getString(R.string.koleso),    lunDayNotif,    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentTL,    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));    /*код*/    } else {}

Comment: Запретить установку на api 23 нельзя